# ETC1 texture compression on desktop?

Tags: opengl, textures

I was wondering how could I load an ETC1 compressed texture in a desktop application as it seems ETC1 is only meant for mobile.

Specifically I was hoping to know if a variant of `GL_ETC1_RGB8_OES` exists for openGL 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot (in general. [NVIDIA offers a way to create an ES 2.0 context](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/wgl_create_context_es2_profile.txt), where you might have better luck); you'll have to decompress it and use it as a decompressed texture.

The general way this is handled is to build your textures for the various platforms of interest. You use the various S3TC formats on desktop GL, ETC1 on platforms where that exists, PVR's on those platforms, etc. The source of all of these is the original uncompressed texture.